# QByteArray en 2 partes?

Tags: c++, qt

Buenas tardes, estoy haciendo un ejercicio que involucra Puerto Serial, enviar y recibir una cadena, al momento de mandar la cadena todo bien, pero al recibirla la obtengo en 2 partes, ambos dispositivos tienen la misma configuración

```
PuertoAP->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
PuertoAP->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
PuertoAP->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
PuertoAP->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
PuertoAP->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
```

Es una cadena de 15 datos, primero llegan 8 y luego 7, si pongo el tamaño de la cadena a 24 me parte la cadena en 3 partes de 8 datos, Alguien sabe a que se deba? muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alguien sabe a que se deba?

Se debe a que es así como funciona. Los datos nunca se envían enteros si no en paquetes tanto si quieres enviar varios gigas de información como si envías pequeñas cadenas.

---

#### ¿Qué debes hacer?

Normalmente, implementando este tipo de comunicaciones los mensajes se envían con una cabecera que incluye el tamaño de la información a recibir y no se considera la información recibida hasta haber obtenido el dato al completo.

Comment: Hice un programa para probar la comunicación (Otro aparte del principal) con el fin de descartar que sea la programación, y el programa responde bien solo en una computadora al recibir llega todo el paquete completo y en la otra computadora al recibir llega en 2 partes. la otra pc es una ARK-1120 y estoy probando en el puerto ttyS0 esta es la que tiene el problema, mientras en en la laptop recibo bien los paquetes

Comment: La manera en cómo se dividen los paquetes es dependiente del sistema de comunicación que haya debajo. El sistema de comunicación no forma parte del estándar (iba a ser estandarizado en C++17 pero creo que no llegó). Así pues, es el Sistema Operativo el que entre bambalinas hace la comunicación y puede decidir (o no) dividir el mensaje en paquetes si lo cree conveniente, no puedes tomar control sobre este comportamiento.

Comment: Gracias por la información @PaperBirdMaster, Ya no te pude contestar ese día pero lo que hice fue hacer una función que una estas dos mitades al recibirlas, solo que después, mientras debugeaba el proyecto detecté otro problema, después de un tiempo me duplica los paquetes, manda dos veces la primera mitad y dos veces la segunda mitad, lo pude resolver pero me preocupa que pueda multiplicar los paquetes mas veces y que esto cause que el programa se pare